# Applying filters in the custom column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this. I would like to filter with column Name "A.

```
select 'DummyValue1' as ColumnNameA 
  from TableT.
```

Now I would like to apply filter like

```
select 'DummyValue1' as ColumnNameA 
  from TableT 
 where ColumnNameA  = "Value1" .
```

How do I do it in Oracle.

Please note here 'DummyValue1' as ColumnNameA  is not actually a database column. I am just creating in my result set.

Comment: What is your final goal? Obviously writing such a query would have almost no practical reason. You will ether return `'DummyValue1'` string literal as many times as many rows exists in the `TableT` if `DummyValue1=Value1` or your query will return no result otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use an alias in `WHERE` clause because of the query processing order. But you can use an outer select or CTE for something like that

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM
(
  SELECT 'DummyValue1' as ColumnNameA, ... 
    FROM TableT 
) t
 WHERE ColumnNameA = 'Value1'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf4e6/6)** demo

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the query remains the same, only the string literal in the `WHERE` clause of the query need to be enclosed in single quotes, because string literal, in Oracle, that enclosed in double quotes will be considered as identifier:

```
select 'DummyValue1' as ColumnNameA 
  from TableT 
 where ColumnNameA  = 'Value1'
```

Comment: That will give `ORA-00904: "COLUMNNAMEA": invalid identifier : ...` error

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
SELECT ColumnNameA as 'DummyValue1'
FROM TableT
WHERE ColumnNameA = 'Value1'
```

Comment: That will give `ORA-00904: "COLUMNNAMEA": invalid identifier : ...` error

Comment: How come? This error should appear if the "WHERE" clause was written as "WHERE DummyValue1 = 'Value1'", shouldn't it? Otherwise this should work properly.

Comment: @peterm is right - the wording of the OP's question implies that the table does not have a column called `ColumnNameA`.